# Where to get the raw html code in dash/layout/html to print local pdf after executing dash app?

Tags: python, html, pdf, report, plotly-dash

I want to write a report and am using dash-financial-report as a template.
So when the code is executed I did a subprocess which creates a pdf with `xhtml2pdf` (probably not the best idea but anyway).

Where can I get the plain HTML which is somehow stored in the app.layout?

Comment: You must pass the plain HTML to xhtml2pdf, so review your code around the part the PDF is generated and it will be there.

Comment: 1. Thanks.
2. The plane html is hidden in dash or in flask behind. 
```dash.Dash().layout``` / ```html.Div()```
My problem is to get the plane html from dash when the layout is created